# How to place an JSX.Element above the svg element?

Tags: css

I want to make a light-mist effect on the background. But I'm having trouble with this

Current situation:
[My current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cflnQ.jpg)

Code:
I'm using react with tailwindcss. This is the code of page layout.

```
...
<body className="bg-main_background">
    <NavigationBar /> // ← applied styles: fixed z-50 ...
    {children}
    <Mist_1 /> // ← returns a single <svg> element
...
```

Design:
[A design with light-mist effect on the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcnB9.jpg)

What CSS should I apply to make this code to be like my design?
I tried to apply `relevant` and set z-index value but still it doesn't work.

Comment: I just solved my problem..!

```
...
<body className="bg-main_background relative">
    <Mist_1 /> // ← with absolute
    <NavigationBar />
    {children}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to achieve the light-mist effect on the background, you'll need to position the  element containing the mist effect absolutely and set its z-index to a lower value than the NavigationBar. This will ensure that the mist effect is displayed behind the NavigationBar and other page elements.

Try  this CSS code :

```
.mist-effect {


position: absolute;
top: 0; 
left: 0;
 width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: -1; /* Set z-index to a lower value than the `NavigationBar` */
background-image: url('/path/to/mist-effect.svg');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Apply this CSS class to the  element containing the mist effect:

```
<Mist_1 className="mist-effect" />
```